# External class-calling

Tags: c++, class, callback, external

Hi guys i have a bit of a problem with a few classes, and i would be very grateful if someone can help me out. So i have:

1. Already compiled executable (for
   whom i don't have the source)
2. A class in that program that i want to call

The program doesn't have export for the class, and that's my problem i don't have definition for this class, so is there a way to get a callback to this class?

Example:
In the compiled executable:

```
foo::bar (example) { printf(example); }
```

My app:

```
CALLBACK(foo::bar, "this text must be passed as argument")
```

Or in other words i want to call a class in other executable (without having its source) and pass arguments to its function.

Comment: Any work-around to this problem?

Comment: When I said you can't do that, what do you think I meant?

Comment: I hoped there is a way, else my project is dead

Comment: I wish to offer my sincere and deepest condolences for your loss.

Comment: Hope its not sarcastic, anyway thanks for the help Neil.

Answer (score 0):

if your executable(application ) can take that argument as command line argument you can call that application with command line argument as that parameter

for example in win32 API

```
LPTSTR szCmdline = _tcsdup(TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\MyApp -L -S"));
    CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdline, /* ... */);
```

That is at max you can do with any application...
-L and -S will pass as argument to MyApp